# How to center simpleCart_items in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, simplecart

I am using Bootstrap to create a sales page and have decided to use simpleCartjs as my java plugin for the cart. I'm calling on .simpleCart_items to display my cart. I can easily center the cart on a page without bootstrap. I've used every bootstrap class imaginable to try to center it. (span, text-centered, row-fluid, pagination-centered, ect) The cart output is in the form of a table. Any ideas. I'd like to maintain my bootstrap navbar for the checkout page or else I would just create a check out page without bootstrap.

Comment: Using the grid system you can do something like this: `<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">centered</div>`.

Comment: Just tried that. In fullscreen it pushes like 15% to far to the right. At any other screen width it floats left.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

`cartStyle: 'div',`

Like:

```
 simpleCart({
            cartColumns: [blaaa],
            cartStyle: 'div',
     });
```